# ¿Porque no me funciona en el servidor el proyecto boostrap y php?

Tags: php, html, bootstrap

Hola hize un proyecto Boostrap para hacer un carrito de compras con integracion de Paypal, para hacer las pruebas locales utilizo xampp en un servidor apache y mysql con php 7.2 (localhost)

intente subir este proyecto en dos servidores ubuntu y debian. Uno de ellos tenia php 7.4 y el servidor debian tenia php 7.0 ambos servidores con apache2 y mysql y phpmyadmin.

El prolema es que en localhost con xamp el proyecto funciona bien pero cuando intento subirlo a un servidor (VPS) al presionar los distintos botones como agregar al carrito o algo similar simplemente no redirige ni realiza ninguna accion.

les dejare el codigo del index.php

```
    <?php
include 'global/config.php';
include 'global/conexion.php';
include 'carrito.php';
include 'template/cabecera.php';
?>


  <br>
  <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
     <?php echo $mensaje; ?>
      <a href="#" class="badge badge-success">Ver Carrito</a>
  </div>
 <div class="row">

 <?php

 $sentencia=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tblproductos`");
 $sentencia->execute();
 $listaProductos=$sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 

 ?>

 <?php foreach($listaProductos as $producto){ ?>

    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="card">
          <img 
          title=Curso Hacking Etico"
          alt="Curso Hacking"
          class="card-img-top" 
          src="<?php echo $producto['Imagen'];?>"
          data-toggle="popover"
          data-trigger="hover"
          data-content="<?php echo $producto['Descripcion'];?>"
          >
          <div class="card-body">
          <span><?php echo $producto['Nombre']; ?></span>
              <h5 class="card-title">$<?php echo $producto['Precio']; ?></h5>
              <p class="card-text">Descripcion</p>
              <form action="" method="post">
              <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt($producto['ID'],COD,KEY);  ?>">
              <input type="hidden" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt($producto['Nombre'],COD,KEY); ?>">
              <input type="hidden" name="precio" id="precio" value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt($producto['Precio'],COD,KEY); ?>">
              <input type="hidden" name="cantidad" id="cantidad" value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt(1,COD,KEY); ?>">
              
              <button class="btn btn-primary" name="btnAccion" value="Agregar" type="submit">Agregar al carrito</button>
              </form>
             
          </div>
      </div>
     </div>
 </div>

 <?php } ?>


?>




  
  </div>

  <script>
  
  $(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})
  
  
  </script>

  <?php
  include 'template/pie.php'
  
  ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Este proyecto lo copie de un tutorial en youtube y por lo que tengo entendido utiliza Boostrap, no se que debere realizar ya que en localhost con xampp me funciona bien pero en los servidores no, quizas deba instalar alguna extension en PHP para que funcione correctamente.

En xampp utilizo php 7.2

he probado en los servidores con php 7.0 y php 7.4 y es lo mismo no funciona, agradeceria si me pueden ayudar, si nesesitan el proyecto completo tambien se los puedo pasar, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa los archivos de conexión a base de datos, en cpanel cuando asignas un usuario a una base de datos debes de darle todos los privilegios igual, te recomiendo que habilites los errores para ver que errores te da al ejecutar el archivo.

```
<?php
// Motrar todos los errores de PHP
error_reporting(-1);

// No mostrar los errores de PHP
error_reporting(0);

// Motrar todos los errores de PHP
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Motrar todos los errores de PHP
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
?>
```

Comment: no estoy utilizando cpanel utilizo el servidor raiz en un virtual private server(vps) no me podrias ayudar es que no me anda el proyecto y en localhost con xampp si me anda

Comment: donde lo tienes hospedado? ha de ser un problema de configuracion

Comment: EL VPS es de la compañia digital ocean, intente multiple plataformas como Debian, ubuntu, y centos pero siempre pasa lo mismo

Comment: es algo obvio, pero configuraste los permisos de la base de datos? en el archivo de configuracion de php ini configura que se muestren los errores.